# Sa'ad : Correct spelling in English and French

Tags: names

We are considering naming our child the Arabic name Sa'ad (سعد).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saad

The Arabic spelling has an ع which I am not sure how to spell. I have seen it spelled as Saad which has the potential to be mispronounced.

The wikipedia lists it as Sa'ad, where the apostrophe separates both syllables. I currently favor this spelling.

My question is: Is there a spelling other than Sa'ad which is more descriptive of how to pronounce the name properly?

Comment: I guess it's pronounced /ˈsɑ:ˈɑ:d/ but without actually knowing the pronunciation, it's difficult to say anything at all. [Hmm: comments don't like IPA]

Comment: I disagree with the close-voters; this is not a question of naming, but of orthography (“How do I represent this pronunciation as faithfully as possible?”), which is within the scope of the site.

Comment: "Sa'ad" would not be understood as a name in spelling, and if pronounced correctly in the Arabic fashion, no English speaker would register the uvular fricative (or what ever the 'ain' is). You won't be able to be faithful to the Arabic -and- be understood  by English speakers. "Saad" is probably the closest that will be pronounceable by English speakers. Frankly, the double a, even without the "'", will be difficult for English speakers to manage to your satisfaction.

Comment: THe same goes for French, but I suggest you ask at French.SE for them (it may be on topic and no too local there.

Comment: For example, find how others have previously spelled it in English ... http://www.mybirthcare.com/favorites/M/Muslim/meaning.asp?name=Sa'ad

Comment: Too bad the question is closed, I think it is a good one. For what it's worth, I fully support the apostrophe (in English anyway, I don't know about French). I have seen an apostrophe used in other Arabic as well as Hebrew names *that were given to children growing up in fully English-speaking contexts*. I think it works better than the umlaut and the hyphen suggested in Jon Purdy's answer. If you leave it as "Saad" it'll look too much like "sad" which isn't the meaning you're after!

Comment: I added a youtube video which describes how I pronounce it. I linked it from a new question on the same topic [ http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74570/correct-spelling] since this question is closed.

Answer (score 2):

An apostrophe doesn’t really make sense there. Apostrophes typically stand for elided letters (e.g., “don’t”), and occasionally for a glottal stop, which “ع” is not (it’s a pharyngeal fricative).

There is also a tendency for beginning fantasy writers to come up with names involving lots of extra apostrophes and accents to make them look more fantastical—a phenomenon which I affectionally call the Dread Apostrophe. For that reason I’m not fond of apostrophes in names.

The standard way in English of indicating that two vowels are to be pronounced separately is with diaeresis, as in the word “naïve”. **Saäd** looks pretty good and would be my first choice—it’s also correct in French orthography. You’d be likely to run into issues of representation in computer systems, however—English-speaking operators would probably just type **Saad**.

If you must use punctuation, then a hyphen is also possible: **Sa-ad**. However, since the name is largely unknown to English speakers, they will probably pronounce it as “sad” or “sard” (non-rhotic) no matter how you spell or punctuate it.

Comment: I've read all the comments here, and looked at a few different websites as well, and I'm still uncertain that I've figured out how to pronounce Sa’ad.  (Still, that's not saying the name shouldn't be used; I wouldn't have known how to pronounce Sade either, if her band had not acheived acclaim).

Comment: I redrafted the question and posted a new one at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74570/correct-spelling. It contains a youtube link which pronounces the name saad. I looked at how ä is pronounced and I think it is fairly close to what I am looking for. Can you please verify and if possibly add this answer over there too? Thanks.